# Chain of decorators in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to use decorators to achieve filtering of list of objects. I have a list of objects and I need to filter out only integers and further filter out only even numbers. And then finally I need to apply a sum function that sums up the even numbers. Following are my functions:

```
def number_filter(function):
    print 'i am number_filter and function is ' + function.__name__
    def wrapper3(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'wrapper3 args: ' + repr(args)
        l = []
        for a in args:
            try:
                l.append(int(a))
            except ValueError:
                pass
            except TypeError:
                pass                
        return function(l)
    return wrapper3

def even_number_filter(function):
    print 'i am even_number_filter and function is ' + function.__name__
    def wrapper1(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'wrapper1 args: ' + repr(args)
        l = [i for i in args if i % 2 == 0]
        return function(l)
    return wrapper1

def sum_fn(args):
    return sum(args)
```

Following calls work independently perfect:

```
>>> number_filter(sum_fn)(1,2,'',10, {}, None)
i am number_filter and function is sum_fn
wrapper3 args: (1,2,'',10, {}, None)
13
>>> even_number_filter(sum_fn)(1,2,10)
i am even_number_filter and function is sum_fn
wrapper1 args: (1, 2, 10)
12
```

What I want is a way to use the two decorators defined above to finally get a summation of even numbers. Note that input is the list `(1,2,'',10, {}, None)` and expected output is `12`

PS: This is not the real problem I am trying to solve but closely resembles the pattern I am trying to use, that is, I need way to pipe my data stream through several filters in order to get what I want. I am aware of creating a chain of functions (similar to chain of responsibilities pattern) to solve this problem. Wanted to make sure if this is possible via decorators or not.

Comment: So what happens when you do `even_number_filter(number_filter(sum_fn))(1,2,'',10, {}, None)` ? Not what you wanted? Personally I recommend functional-style programming (e.g., the toolz package) for this kind of pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your functions to handle `*args` and `**kwargs` properly (you're currently mismatching single sequence arguments and `*args` packing/unpacking), but once you've done that it's easy to nest decorators:

```
>>> def number_filter(function):
    print 'i am number_filter and function is ' + function.__name__
    def wrapper3(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'wrapper3 args: ' + repr(args)
        l = []
        for a in args:
            try:
                l.append(int(a))
            except ValueError:
                pass
            except TypeError:
                pass                
        return function(*l, **kwargs) # pass filtered args and unfiltered kwargs
    return wrapper3

>>> def even_number_filter(function):
    print 'i am even_number_filter and function is ' + function.__name__
    def wrapper1(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'wrapper1 args: ' + repr(args)
        l = [i for i in args if i % 2 == 0]
        return function(*l, **kwargs) # same again
    return wrapper1

>>> @number_filter # filter out non-numbers first
@even_number_filter # then odd numbers
def sum_fn(*args, **kwargs): # handle arbitrary arguments 
    return sum(args)

i am even_number_filter and function is sum_fn
i am number_filter and function is wrapper1
>>> sum_fn(1,2,'',10, {}, None) # note separate arguments, not a single sequence
wrapper3 args: (1, 2, '', 10, {}, None)
wrapper1 args: (1, 2, 10)
12 # success!
```

Note that both of your decorators do a similar thing, so you could refactor to a `filter_args` decorator:

```
>>> import functools
>>> def filter_args(f):
    def decorates(fn):
        @functools.wraps(fn) # wrap decorators to handle docstrings
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return fn(*filter(f, args), **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorates

>>> @filter_args(lambda i: i % 2 == 0)
def sum_args(*args, **kwargs):
    """Sum the positional arguments."""
    return sum(args)

>>> sum_args(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
6
```